# How to instance a modifier?

Tags: modifiers

I want to add a modifier to a bunch of objects but after adding one, its parameters affect only a certain object, not the rest which have inherited that modifier via Ctrl L = Make Links: Modifiers. 
So the question is how I am supposed to add a "single" modifier to a selection of objects or make an instance of that modifier? The idea is to control different objects via a single modifier that is shared among them. Hope it's not that convoluted.

In Max you normally do it by cloning and then paste-instancing a modifier through the Right-click menu in the Modifier Stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you have to use drivers, as far as I know a Modifier belongs only to one object so it cant affect other objects as you imagine.
In your case I would create a controller object (an empty for instance) or just a property in my main object so I can control the rest.

Comment: Modifiers can be linked between objects, no?

Comment: Not really, link has an ambiguous meaning here. Modifiers are being copied although you press ctrl+l. It is being used to instantly copy to the rest of the objects of your selection the active's one.

Comment: Thanks, cnisidis! I'll give it a go tomorrow. @Leo Modifiers can indeed be linked between objects but they become independent.

Comment: @ilyak exactly !